# Retrieving user defined values in Plist

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I'm trying to retrieve user-defined build settings in my .plist. 
I'm working on a Mac app and I'm using the Info.plist (shouldn't be a custom one, right?)

I use the following code to retrieve my values from the Plist:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    defaults.set(nil, forKey: "access_token")
    defaults.set(nil, forKey: "refresh_token")
    self.userLoggedOut()

    let em = NSAppleEventManager.shared()
    em.setEventHandler(self, andSelector: #selector(self.getUrl(_:withReplyEvent:)), forEventClass: AEEventClass(kInternetEventClass), andEventID: AEEventID(kAEGetURL))

    var myDict: NSDictionary?
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Info", ofType: "plist") {
        myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
        let serverURLString = myDict?.object(forKey: "SERVER_URL") as! String
        let appNameString = myDict?.object(forKey: "APP_NAME") as! String
        print(serverURLString)
        print(appNameString)
        Constant.apiUrlString = serverURLString
        Constant.applicationName = appNameString
    }
}
```

This will print: 
`$(YT_SERVER_URL)`
`$(YT_APP_NAME)`

My plist looks like this:

[image]

I've added my user-defined build settings in my Project > Targets

[image]

Why can't I find the values I've added there? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does myDict return?

Comment: @Rutger checkout the solution. I think it will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can access user-defined values from your `Plist`. To access the  user-defined value from `Plist` you need to add the following code :

```
extension Bundle {
    var apiBaseURL: String {
        return object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "serviceURL") as? String ?? ""
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
let appConfiguration =  Bundle.main.apiBaseURL
```

Your `applicationDidFinishLaunching` will look like this:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    defaults.set(nil, forKey: "access_token")
    defaults.set(nil, forKey: "refresh_token")
    self.userLoggedOut()

    let em = NSAppleEventManager.shared()
    em.setEventHandler(self, andSelector: #selector(self.getUrl(_:withReplyEvent:)), forEventClass: AEEventClass(kInternetEventClass), andEventID: AEEventID(kAEGetURL))

    Constant.apiUrlString = Bundle.main.apiBaseURL
    Constant.applicationName = Bundle.main.appName
}
```

Apart from that, you will need to check the following things

1. Go to Packaging and check `Info Plist` File. it must be your main Info Plist file.
2. Check Info Plist How you have fetched user-defined value in Info Plist file

[image]
[image: Info Plist File]

Comment: I have done a similar thing in one of my projects and it's working great!!!

Comment: I checked your settings vs. my project and it was all the same except for different variable names. Still didn't work... Then I decided to delete all my variables and re-do everything with the exactly the same names / setup that you had. IT WORKS! Thanks Jarvis

Answer (score 0):

Using these lines you can get the Plist dictionary ::

```
guard let path = Bundle(for: *YourClass*.self).url(forResource: "Info", withExtension: "plist"),
      let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOf: path) as? [String: Any]
else {
    return 
}
// Access any key here like :: 
let serverUrl = dict["SERVER_URL"] as? String
```